# RegisterRawInputDevices throws error 0

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on my barcodescanner application, and now I'm stuck at the `RegisterRawInputDevices` function.

`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` always throws the error 0. I can't tell why.
I've got a handle of my current console window and the properties (usagePage, usage, Flags) are set correctly.

Therefore it should be able to register a rawinput-device which my window can listen at.
I'm going through the example code of an [article written by Emma Burrows and Steve Messer at codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard#_Toc156395975).

The Method "InputDevice" is the constructor of the InputDevice class of the WPF example code.

```
/// <summary>
/// InputDevice constructor; registers the raw input devices
/// for the calling window.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hwnd">Handle of the window listening for key presses</param>
public InputDevice(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    RAWINPUTDEVICE[] rid = new RAWINPUTDEVICE[1];

    rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01; // -> set to hid
    rid[0].usUsage = 0x06; // -> set to keyboard
    rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK; // -> set flag to let the window recieve
                                             WM-Messages even if it is not focused
    rid[0].hwndTarget = hwnd; // -> the handle of the window

    if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length,
                                    (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0])))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
        //throw new ApplicationException("Failed to register raw input device(s).");
    }
}
```

In the Program.cs of my application the `StartWndProcHandler()` function is called, the function itself, gets the handler of the window and instances an object of `InputDevice`.

```
// Gets the handler of the window and then instances a new inputdevice object
static void StartWndProcHandler()
{
    IntPtr hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr myWin = GetConsoleWindow();

    try
    {
        hwnd = myWin;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    device = new InputDevice(hwnd); // instances a new inputdevice
    //NumberOfKeyboards = device.EnumerateDevices();
    //device.KeyPressed += device_KeyPressed; 
}
```

I'm sure that I've understood the functionality of the RawInput registering and I've studied the source code to find out what it does.

But now I'm at the end of my wisdom... It simply seems unlogical to me why the application cannot register any device.

I hope someone could give me a hint or an approach.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to extract a detailed error code. It is error 1008 which means, that I wanted to reference a token that doesn't exist. So the solution is a step nearer. :)

**UPDATE (01-12-2014) 2:**

Hello Guys,
After hours of debugging and searching for the problem I was not really able to find a solution.
All needed values are passed to the `RawInputDevice` Struct, but i still get the error 1008.

I've tested the original WPF Demoproject of the article mentioned above. It can register a device without problems, but can't capture the raw input from keyboard.
So the registering of the devices should work i guess.

So i hope that someone eventuelly could give me any advice or aproach.

Best regards

**UPDATE (23-12-2014):**

Hello guys,

we solved the problem completely different. Because we use a debian machine where we connected the scangun, we now were able to read out the scangun input easily with a bashscript. 
The problem is still unsolved, but not focused anymore by us now.

Best regards

Comment: Hello guys,
we solved the problem completely different.
Because we use a debian machine where we connected the scangun, we now were able to read out the scangun input easily with a bashscript.

The problem is still unsolved, but not focused by us now.

Best regards

Comment: I don't really get it - a scan gun either connects via USB (in which case you can either use it as HID and get input like normal keystrokes or you can use a USB-to-COM driver if available, in which case you can use a `SerialPort` to get the input) or it connects using a serial connection, in which case you can again use `SerialPort`. What's your problem here?

Comment: Hello @Thorsten Dittmar,
my problem was, that i didn't get the raw-input api to work. The api was our second option after we tried to read the keystrokes out with a simple console application that listens to the keypressed-event which didn't worked as expected.
In the course of the development process, we decided to run the listener script for the barcode on a linux tablet. So the development of the scan gun listener program was aborted and converted to be applied under linux. And the solution with C# and the rawinput-api was obvious and not further followed.

Comment: I've developed applications working with scanners for over 8 years now and I've never *ever* had to use that API - what's the point?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar As i mentioned above, we cancelled developing the application with the api, because we'd find out an easier way to do it. And in case of that my post about my problems with the api is obsolete because we found a solution to do what we needed. That's what i wanted to say with the update at my post. 

Hmmm...could it be that i'm missunderstood what you want me to tell?
Best regards

Comment: I understand that your post is obsolete. I'm just wondering whether you actually misunderstood how to handle inputs from barcode scanners in the first place, because in all the time I've never had to handle it using the API you've mentioned.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar
Oh...now i understood...
The reason for this is that i'm just oversaw the simple things. At my researches i found many tutorials where people using the api or so called hooks into the interface of the keyboard. 
Looking back from now i think that i maybe focused to much on that api and hook-stuff, so that i had overseen the simple and much practicablier ways to go combined with a big piece of unexperience in writting desktop software and dealing with/ handling keyboard or hid input.